# Apache não lê subdiretórios

Tags: php, apache, linux

Olá,

Estou iniciando com o Linux agora e estou tentando configurar um servidor Apache para fins de teste.
Estou utilizando o Debian 9 e já fiz a instalação do Apache, PHP 7.0, libs e MariaDB.

Através do navegador utilizando o http://ip-do-server carrega o index.html que está dentro de /var/www/html/ normalmente porem se eu crio um novo diretório dentro, por exemplo, /var/www/html/teste/ e coloco qualquer arquivo, não consigo acessar pelo navegador.

Alguma dica de como resolver? Falta alguma permissão?
Ao criar o diretório já rodei um chmod 777 nele.

Obrigado desde já.

---

No navegador aparece a seguinte mensagem:

Esta página não está funcionando
192.168.0.101 não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
HTTP ERROR 500

Em /var/log/apache2/error.log aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[Wed Jan 10 09:21:42.054246 2018] [:error] [pid 480] [client 192.168.0.9:55441] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/gra/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Aparece algum erro no navegador? Se possível verifique os logs do Apache em `/var/log/apache2` e poste o erro em sua pergunta utilizando o [edit]

Comment: Aplica um `chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html` e um `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html` e teste o código php com `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Perfeito Valdeir, deu certo. Era permissão mesmo. Muito obrigado!